# Haskell-function to convert lower case char to uppercase char

Tags: haskell

I've stumbled across some code in a Haskell tutorial that does not seem to work for me.

```
fromEnum :: Char -> Int
toEnum :: Int -> Char

offset :: Int
offset = fromEnum 'A' - fromEnum 'a'

toUpper :: Char -> Char
toUpper ch = toEnum (fromEnum ch + offset)
```

The text book from which this excerpt is taken states that the following conversion function will convert a lower case Char to an upper case one. However when I try running the script I get the following error message:

```
eval.hs:1:1:
    The type signature for ‘fromEnum’ lacks an accompanying binding
      (The type signature must be given where ‘fromEnum’ is declared)

eval.hs:2:1:
    The type signature for ‘toEnum’ lacks an accompanying binding
      (The type signature must be given where ‘toEnum’ is declared)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I'm new to Haskell, so can someone tell me what I'm missing here? Is the textbook wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove these lines:

```
fromEnum :: Char -> Int
toEnum :: Int -> Char
```

These functions are already defined by the standard library. By adding the above lines, you are attempting to redefine them, which triggers the error.

The tutorial probably is mentioning they exist, and is not inviting you to add these functions in your program.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess I could probably use `import Prelude hiding (...)` as well, although that would perhaps be pointless.

Comment: @Bolboa Yes, you could. But the youn would need to implement those functions -- your code provided only their type signatures, not their actual code.